# Extract audio to mp3 from mp4 using C++ (not executing ffmpeg with args)

Tags: c++, mp3, mp4, converters

How can I programmatically convert (extract the audio channel) from the mp4 video file format?
I just can't find anything on the web, for using C++.

Passing command line args to LAME or MPLAYER or FFMPEG is not an option.

Comment: LAME and FFMPEG are open source projects, so I suggest you take a peek at their sources to get you started.

Comment: how about using the ffmpeg API? implementing that from scratch sounds difficult.

Comment: does FFMPEG have API ???

Comment: @user63898 I tried to improve the grammar and removed 1 sentence because I couldn't understand what it was supposed to mean. It'd be nice if you could clarify that sentence if it was important.

Comment: I am looking for code example to achieve this using ffmpeg.

Comment: "_does FFMPEG have API ???:_" - [This document describes the usage of the different libraries provided by FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/index.html) (the API)

Answer (score 11):

You can try using ffmpeg to do it in C or C++. Here is the normal flow of steps.

1. Init ffmpeg using  av_register_all();
2. Open input file using avformat_open_input( &informat, sourcefile, 0, 0)).
3. Find stream info using avformat_find_stream_info(informat, 0)).
4. Find the audio stream by iterating through streams and comparing codec_type to AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO.
5. Once you have input audio stream you can find audio decoder and open the decoder. Use    avcodec_find_decoder(in_aud_strm->codec->codec_id) and avcodec_open2(in_aud_codec_ctx, in_aud_codec, NULL).
6. Now for output file guess the outformat using av_guess_format(NULL, (const char*)outfile, NULL).
7. Allocate context for outformat.
8. Find output audio encoder using avcodec_find_encoder(outfmt->audio_codec).
9. Add new stream audio stream avformat_new_stream(outformat, out_aud_codec).
10. Fill output codec context with desired sample rate, sample fmt, channel etc.
11. Open output file using avio_open().
12. Write the output headers using avformat_write_header(outformat, NULL).
13. Now in while loop start reading packet, decode only audio packet encode them and write them in opened output file. You can use av_read_frame(informat, &pkt) ,  avcodec_decode_audio4(in_aud_codec_ctx, pframeT, &got_vid_pkt, &pkt), avcodec_encode_audio2() and av_write_frame().
14. Finally write trailer using av_write_trailer.

You can looking into demuxing.c and muxing.c provided in ffmpeg examples.

Comment: Thanks i will try it. I wander if there some open source app that allready doing it

Comment: It would be very useful if you provided some code example

Comment: @user63898 this is exactly what **ffmpeg** does (and it is open source). The question was how this can be done in C.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the [transcode_aac](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcode_aac.c) official example. We need remarkably few changes:

1. add a global variable at file scope:

   ```
   /* The index of audio stream that will be transcoded */
   static int audio_stream_idx = -1;
   ```
2. in `open_input_file()`, replace lines [83-88](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcode_aac.c#L83) with

   ```
   for (audio_stream_idx = 0; audio_stream_idx < (*input_format_context)->nb_streams; audio_stream_idx++) {
   if ((*input_format_context)->streams[audio_stream_idx]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
       break;
   }

   if (audio_stream_idx >= (*input_format_context)->nb_streams) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Could not find an audio stream\n");
       avformat_close_input(input_format_context);
       return AVERROR_EXIT;
   }
   ```
3. On lines [92](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcode_aac.c#L92) and [107](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcode_aac.c#L107), replace `streams[0]` with `streams[audio_stream_idx]`.
4. On line [181](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcode_aac.c#L181), replace hard-coded codec ID `AV_CODEC_ID_AAC` with

   ```
   (*output_format_context)->oformat->audio_codec
   ```
5. On line [182](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcode_aac.c#L182), replace the error message:

   ```
   fprintf(stderr, "Could not find audio encoder for %s(%d).\n", (*output_format_context)->oformat->long_name, (*output_format_context)->oformat->audio_codec);
   ```
6. In `decode_audio_frame()` we skip non-audio frames: on line [389](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcode_aac.c#L389), write

   ```
   if (error != AVERROR_EOF && input_packet.stream_index != audio_stream_idx) goto cleanup;
   ```

**PS** Note that this solution does not handle optimally the case when the audio stream [does not require transcoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62200007/192373). Most **mp4** files will have AAC or AC3 audio tracks, so make sure you build your ffmpeg with the relevant decoders and with an MP3 encoder (e.g. [shine](https://github.com/savonet/shine)).

**PPS** [here](https://github.com/alexcohn/mobile-ffmpeg/blob/49d82539a9f391d67e3bf6fe96cf5cabb1bd7ce3/android/app/src/main/cpp/doc_examples_transcode_aac.c) is the file, adapted to Adnroid.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it on multiple `mp4` files and I get `"Could not find an AAC encoder."` from [this](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcode_aac.c#L182) line.

Comment: @＿Static＿assert how did you build your **libavcodec**? Actually, the message is misleading: I fixed my answer above

Comment: I installed the library through Microsoft package manager (`vcpkg`). Your print statement on step 4 didn't compile, so I replaced it with `if (!((output_codec = avcodec_find_encoder((*output_format_context)->oformat->audio_codec)))) {fprintf(stderr, "Could not find audio encoder for %s(%d).\n",(*output_format_context)->oformat->long_name,(*output_format_context)->audio_codec_id);` And the output of the program is **"Could not find audio encoder for MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)(0)."**

Comment: After adding the print, the output **"Could not find audio encoder for MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)(86017)"**

Comment: Sorry, my copy/paste fault about this compilation error. But you got the idea. Your package manager brought you a version of ffmpeg that cannot create mp3. Probably related: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/9671