# How to use ffmpeg to decode speex stream?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, speex

I want to decode speex stream and extract audio from it.

I've heard FFmpeg support speex codec, but i don't know how to use it.

Is there any code sample about decoding speex stream data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131805/extract-audio-to-mp3-from-mp4-using-c-not-executing-ffmpeg-with-args

Comment: Note that you will need to compile (or find a build of) FFmpeg with `--enable-libspeex` to decode this.

Comment: yes it does, and yes it can be a huge pain. follow the above and make sure your using at least ffmpeg 1.1 or above. if your brave there are also ways to add your own driver to ffmpeg. We've had measured success with doing that even with older versions of ffmpeg.

Comment: Special thank to Sat, LordNeckbeard and Michelle Cannon, I am testing those instructions